# Асинхронное добавление записей в MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, asyncio

Имеется парсер, который написан на lxml + asyncio + aiohttp, который добавляет записи в MySQL.

Тип базы данных: EAV, поэтому количество добавляемых записей у одной страницы очень много. (100 страниц, добавляют 17000 записей в последнюю таблицу).

Имеется ошибка, которая описана на этой странице [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907272/python-error-task-pending-coroutine)

В связи с добавлением большого количества записей в бд, создается задержка, из-за чего задерживается и вся программа.

Необходимо как то снизить задержку на добавление записей в БД.

В первую очередь,  я добавил команду `LIMIT 1` так как результатом могло быть только 1 запись, но серьезного ускорения я не добился

В качестве библиотеки я использую mysql.connector. Думаю она синхронная, и хотел бы спросить есть ли асинхронные библиотеки для работы с MySQL.

Возможно вы дадите рекомендации по коду, так как я никак еще не исправил ошибку связанную, с тем что при закрытии start_main(), у меня остаются еще не завершенные задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте переписать на https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql . Конечно придется пройтись по всему коду и заменить вызовы. Использование пула коннектов в разы улучшает отзывчивость приложения.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но уже поздно, уже сдал заказчику. Но все равно спасибо, буду использовать в будущих проектах